# Mandrill resend an already sent email, not reschedule

Tags: api, laravel, laravel-4, mandrill

I'm playing with the Mandrill API:

> https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.php.html

So far so good, but i can't figure out how to resend an email.

Closest I can find is "reschedule" - but that is for already scheduled emails. When i try that, it doesn't recognise the ID of any emails I tell it to find:

> No message exists with the id 'long id here'

The reason i want this is because from time to time, my clients want to resend certain emails.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sent messages' contents are only stored by Mandrill for 24 hours, by default.

You can pay for extended storage of sent emails, but you're likely better off regenerating the email on your end when necessary.

Comment: That is really good to know because it does change things. But can an email be resent even if time wasn't a factor. Because even minutes and hours after the mail was sent I couldn't resend them